# WiFi Secondary Mode

Tags: linux, wifi

According to the `iwconfig` man page, the possible modes for a WiFi interface are:

- Ad-Hoc (network composed of only one cell and without Access Point)
- Managed (node connects to a network composed of many Access Points, with roaming)
- Master (the node is the synchronisation master or acts as an Access Point)
- Repeater (the node forwards packets between other wireless nodes)
- Secondary (the node acts as a backup master / repeater
- Monitor (the node is not associated  with  any cell and passively monitor all packets on the frequency)

Does the *Secondary* option imply that it's possible to set up more than one access point device on a single WiFi network - ie. to extend the range of the network without having to move between different SSIDs?

If so, can someone point me to some documentation on doing this on Linux?